# QuickFix C++: getting total size of FIX::Message passed to FIX::Application::fromApp()

Tags: c++, quickfix

I’m using QFIX_1_13_3 and I have the a question regarding the C++ API.
Is FIX::Message::bodyLength() (with default arguments) the correct API to call within FIX::Application::fromApp() in order to obtain the total size of the incoming binary message FIX::Message? From here it looks like it is, but just wanted to confirm:

http://www.quickfixengine.org/quickfix/doc/html/_message_8h_source.html#l00062

```
00197   int bodyLength( int beginStringField = FIELD::BeginString, 
00198                   int bodyLengthField = FIELD::BodyLength, 
00199                   int checkSumField = FIELD::CheckSum ) const
00200   { return m_header.calculateLength(beginStringField, bodyLengthField, checkSumField)
00201            + calculateLength(beginStringField, bodyLengthField, checkSumField)
00202            + m_trailer.calculateLength(beginStringField, bodyLengthField, checkSumField);
00203   }
```

What I intend to do is memcpy into a memory mapped file the entire received message FIX::Message :

```
void fromApp( const FIX::Message& message, const FIX::SessionID& sessionID ) {
  ...
  memcpy(persistFilePos, &message, message::bodyLength());
}
```

Does this make sense?

Comment: The memcpy of an object is always fishy. Why don't you just copy the string message rather than the whole object ??

Comment: DumbCoder: thank you, it looks like that's what I will need to do